# QVariant wrapped pointers turn to null in QML

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qml, qvariant

It seems like something is going wrong when pointer values transcend between C++ and QML world. I am using the plain old `fromValue()` and `value()` to convert to and from `void *`, and it does work as expected as long as the variant stays on the C++ side.

The moment it is returned to QML, it now resolves to `null`, and when passed back to C++, the variant type is changed from `void *` to `std::nullptr_t` and the value is null.

```
returning 0x3ba5b10 // created
converting to qvariant 0x3ba5b10 // converting
converted QVariant(void*, 0x3ba5b10) 0x3ba5b10 // now variant, testing value() - all good
qml: null // in qml
received QVariant(std::nullptr_t, (nullptr)) 0x0 // back in c++
```

I am using:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(void*)
qRegisterMetaType<void*>();
```

Any clue as to what is going on here?

Edit: it keeps even more strange, I get it to work by casting the pointer values to 64 bit uint and back, but upon the transition to QML, the type info gets messed up, in C++ the variant is of type `qulonglong`, arriving back from QML it is now a `double`, hence the suspicion it might round something and mess up the pointer value.

Edit 2: note that the question is not about recommending practices but about why this doesn't work as expected and observed prior to reaching QML.

Comment: Could you provide minimal working example, please?

Comment: Why are you registering void* in the type-system? It is already there: QMetaType::VoidStar 31 void *  (from [enum QMetaType::Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Type-enum))

Comment: @user6556709 yes I am aware of that, but just in case, and because QVariant didn't have it as part of the API. It doesn't make a difference.

Comment: For your edit: Have you unpacked/repacked it trough JS? If so: JS doesn't have integer datatypes. All numbers are doubles.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to register `void*`, rather use the metatype [QMetaType::VoidStar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE).

Note that to register the metatype `SomeCustomType*`, you need to use an alias.

```
using SomeCustomTypePtr = SomeCustomType*;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(SomeCustomTypePtr)
qRegisterMetaType<SomeCustomTypePtr>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't even possible to do such declarations?

According to official documentation on [Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Type)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE):

> This macro makes the type `Type` known to `QMetaType` as long as it provides a public default constructor, a public copy constructor and a public destructor. It is needed to use the type `Type` as a custom type in `QVariant`.
>
> This macro requires that Type is a fully defined type at the point where it is used.

Sounds strange that this works at least in C++ part.

Don't you think that it will be better and straight-forward solution to declare **your type** pointer instead of `void*`?

Comment: There is no type information available here. The runtime is supposed to know what it is. A pointer is essentially just an unsigned integer, so I don't think I am expecting too much when I expect this to work.

Comment: But what's the use in QML than? If you really want it in QML, I would write a wrapper class and register that actually

Comment: @Amfasis the pointer value is not used in QML, it just has to be selected from there and passed back to C++.

Comment: @dtech, so the user should select a hex-number or something? To me it sounds like a bit of weird view/model design